# Opera theme files on Mac OS X

Tags: opera, themes

Where are the theme images stored for Opera on Mac OS X?

I've dug deep in the `Opera.app` package as well as `~/Library/Application Support/com.operaSoftware.Opera` and I've had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Themes are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/com.operasoftware.Opera/themes/`. The pre-installed default themes are not accessible by the user. (They are packaged in a special format—pak—that is hard to access directly.) They are, however, all available on the [Opera themes site](https://addons.opera.com/themes). If you reinstall it from there, it will show up in the aforementioned directory.

Comment: That folder does not exist on my machine. Also, even if it is hard, how do I access the default themes directly?

Comment: @bookcasey, the folder is only created after you install your first theme. The easiest way to access the defaults themes i sthe work-around I suggested. If you really want to use the files on your computer, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633357/how-to-unpack-resources-pak-from-google-chrome Opera uses the same format. This will likely be time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks Aeyoun, I'll look into it. However, the development version of Opera's themes are not available on the Opera themes site, which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I've now uploaded the themes I made to addons.opera.com:

https://addons.opera.com/en/search/?developer=demonstro

Sometime in the near future, we will upload all default themes - old and new. Thanks for pointing out this problem. We are so very embarrassed this hasn't been done from the very start.